# CakePHP 4.x Authentication 2.x - Fatal Error When Initiating

Tags: php, cakephp

I just did a fresh install of CakePHP 4.x (`4.x-dev` to be exact) and installed the Authentication Plugin (`2.x-dev`). I follow the Quickstart guide here: https://github.com/cakephp/authentication/blob/2.x-get/docs/Quick-start-and-introduction.md

I add the necessary use declarations, `implements AuthenticationServiceProviderInterface`, and add the `getAuthenticationService(ServerRequestInterface $request)` function, and necessary middleware additions, but I get a fatal error:

> Fatal error: Declaration of
>   App\Application::getAuthenticationService(Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface
>   $request) must be compatible with
>   Authentication\AuthenticationServiceProviderInterface::getAuthenticationService(Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface
>   $request): Authentication\AuthenticationServiceInterface in
>   /src/Application.php on line 40.

Line 40 is:

```
class Application extends BaseApplication implements AuthenticationServiceProviderInterface
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the return type hint for your `Application::getAuthenticationService()` method.

It should be similar to this https://github.com/cakephp/authentication/blob/master/src/AuthenticationServiceProviderInterface.php#L32

Comment: I did add the return type hint in those docs, and only got it working when I added: `use Authentication\AuthenticationServiceInterface;` which I now see is part of the 2.x docs. However, it throws the error again if I have `getAuthenticationService(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response): AuthenticationServiceInterface` and WORKS if simply `getAuthenticationService(ServerRequestInterface $request): AuthenticationServiceInterface` (removing the $response var) - so I am not sure if more needs to be changed in the branch still.

Comment: The link doesn't exist anymore. Could you update it?